# Auto-Sharing of assign does not trigger GrantAccess

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2016

In my organization, "Set whether reassigned records are shared with the original owner" is enabled and I want to prevent this behavior on specific entity.
But problem is that no "GrantAccess" message throws when the record shares!
I can't detect this sharing event and as a result, unable to prevent this default behavior.

I have solved my issue with hooking a plugin to Update event and on Post-Operation I will revoke the shared access created.

I want to know what Message will be thrown in this situation, if no messages will be thrown, why this is?
Also I will appreciate if somebody has some better solutions for what I want.

Comment: I just tried it on Dynamics 365 9.1 version for GrantAccess PreVal,PreOp and PostOp. It worked for all 3 stages with Plugin Message as "GrantAccess" when sharing record.

Comment: I think OP is saying original owner sharing step does not trigger this message on assigning to a new owner. @AnkUser did you validate that?

Comment: Hmm don’t remember now whether I as user was owner of record. But I will check again

Comment: Tnx @AnkUser. For better understanding of the situation, I will give an example if there is any ambiguous in question. When I share a record with sb else, GrantAccess works smoothly; but when **A** who is owner, reassigns record to user **B**, system _automatically_ shares record with **A** but unfortunately no GantAccess will be thrown.

Comment: Also I would check ModifyAccess message being triggered or not..

Comment: Alright I can confirm that irrespective of owner "GrantAccess" will throw error if sharing a Record ( I tried this manually).
Now @SSgumS when you mean Assign the Plugin Message changes here, it no longer remains "GrantAccess" but it is "Assign".
I think you need two plugin Trigger one "GrantAccess" and other "Assign" this shall do your trick.

Comment: @AnkUser Tnx, but there is an option is settings that will share record automatically when you assign. The example that I said is describing its behavior. In this specific situation no GrantAccess will be thrown. It just throws Update message. (Assign message is now deprecated so no Assign message will be thrown)

Comment: Any update in this?